# How to make background-color of parent, the same as last-child?

Tags: jquery, parent, equals, background-color, children

I am looking to make a parent div change its background-color depending on the color of its child (including css :hover states). This is the best I could come up with, but it doesn't work...

```
if ($('.selector:last-child').css('background-color') == '#dddddd') {
    $('.controler').css('background-color', '#dddddd');
}
else if ($('.selector:last-child').css('background-color') == '#2a2a2a') {
    $('.controler').css('background-color', '#2a2a2a');
}
else {
    $('.controler').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
}
```

Comment: post a fiddle please

Comment: From `css` method docs: "_Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the `background-color` property of the parent using the child:

```
$('.controler').css('background-color', $('.selector:last-child').css('background-color'));
```

Then, you'd just need to trigger this whenever the background color changes.

Answer (score 0):

It happens cause jQuery returns your background not in HEX but in rgb, so u can change your code like

```
if ($('.selector:last-child').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 0)') {
    $('.controler').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 0)');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7tv097u/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny question because if css inheritance. What i suggest is having the child element have "background-color:inherit" and change only the parent element's background color. After that, you will only need the second part of the jsfiddle.
If however you don't want to do that here's an answer: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf9gtvcs/1/)

```
How the heck do you post links to jsFiddle?
```

Comment: The question seems funny till I mention this: your jsfiddle is exactly what I want it to do, except i want it to trigger when another div is hovered too.